# typescript error when working with prisma and postgresql

Tags: typescript, package.json, prisma

https://www.prisma.io/blog/fullstack-nextjs-graphql-prisma-oklidw1rhw

i went through this tutorial on working with postgresql database using prisma. near the end of the tutorial, I encountered the following typescript error at the stage of Seeing the database:

```
npx prisma db seed --preview-feature
```

prisma:warn Prisma "db seed" was in Preview and is now Generally Available.
You can now remove the --preview-feature flag.
prisma:warn The "ts-node" script in the package.json is not used anymore since version 3.0 and can now be removed.
Environment variables loaded from .env
Running seed command `ts-node prisma/seed.ts` ...
/home/superuserfucker/Documents/Code/actualfullstack/awesome-links/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:859
return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes, diagnostics);
^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
prisma/seed.ts:2:10 - error TS2305: Module '"../data/links"' has no exported member 'data'.

2 import { data } from '../data/links'
~~~~

```
at createTSError (/home/superuserfucker/Documents/Code/actualfullstack/awesome-links/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:859:12)
at reportTSError (/home/superuserfucker/Documents/Code/actualfullstack/awesome-links/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:863:19)
at getOutput (/home/superuserfucker/Documents/Code/actualfullstack/awesome-links/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1077:36)
at Object.compile (/home/superuserfucker/Documents/Code/actualfullstack/awesome-links/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1433:41)
at Module.m._compile (/home/superuserfucker/Documents/Code/actualfullstack/awesome-links/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1617:30)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/home/superuserfucker/Documents/Code/actualfullstack/awesome-links/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1621:12)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
```

diagnosticCodes: [ 2305 ]
}

An error occured while running the seed command:
Error: Command failed with exit code 1: ts-node prisma/seed.ts

/prisma/schema.prisma[image]

package.json file:[image]

```
export const links = [
```

{
category: "Open Source",
description: "Fullstack React framework",
id: "8a9020b2-363b-4a4f-ad26-d6d55b51bqes",
imageUrl: "https://nextjs.org/static/twitter-cards/home.jpg",
title: "Next.js",
url: "https://nextjs.org",
},
{
category: "Open Source",
description: "Next Generation ORM for TypeScript and JavaScript",
id: "2a3121b2-363b-4a4f-ad26-d6c35b41bade",
imageUrl: "https://www.prisma.io/images/og-image.png",

```
title: "Prisma",
url: "https://prisma.io",
```

},
{
category: "Open Source",
description: "Utility-fist css framework",
id: "6a9122b2-363b-4a4f-ad26-d6c55b51baed",
imageUrl:
"https://tailwindcss.com/_next/static/media/twitter-large-card.85c0ff9e455da585949ff0aa50981857.jpg",
title: "TailwindCSS",
url: "https://tailwindcss.com",
},
{
category: "Open Source",
description: "GraphQL implementation ",
id: "2ea8cfb0-44a3-4c07-bdc2-31ffa135ea78",
imageUrl: "https://www.apollographql.com/apollo-home.jpg",
title: "Apollo GraphQL",
url: "https://apollographql.com",
},
];

Comment: `Prisma "db seed" was in Preview and is now Generally Available. You can now remove the --preview-feature flag.` and `The "ts-node" script in the package.json is not used anymore since version 3.0 and can now be removed.` should be self-explanatory. Please show content of `../data/links`. Please don't use images, but copy and paste the code.

Comment: @some-user ../data/links added

Comment: You are exporting `links` but not `data`. You cannot import `data` if you didn't export it.

Comment: @some-user and how can i do it correctly?

Comment: @some-user I exported data wrote in the link file export const data = []
the error went away, but now another error has come:

Comment: Instead of data, you can import links like this:
`import { link } from '../data/links'`
Are you getting any other errors?